# How to keep a ribbon inside its parent element?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Bootstrap `.hero-unit` box, and then I have a **Fork me on Github** ribbon that I am displaying in the top left corner of this box.

Usually a ribbon is placed in a corner of the screen, but in the case it isn't. So how do I hide the part of the ribbon that overflows its parent element?

The HTML:

```
<div class="hero-unit my-unit">
  <a class="ribbon" href="#">Fork me on Github</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the parent element:

```
.my-unit {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #cfcece;
}
```

The CSS for the ribbon:

```
.ribbon {
  position:absolute;
  padding:5px 45px;
  width:128px;
  background-color:#555451;
  color:#e5e5e5;
  font-size:13px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:bold;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  border:2px dotted #e5e5e5;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px #383733,0 0 20px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-shadow:0 0 0 #e5e5e5,0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:-80px;
  -ms-transform:rotate(330deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(330deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your HTML should be

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="hero-unit my-unit">
     <a href="#"><img class="ribbon"src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/82b228a3648bf44fc1163ef44c62fcc60081495e/68747470733a2f2f73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f6769746875622f726962626f6e732f666f726b6d655f6c6566745f7265645f6161303030302e706e67" alt="Fork me on GitHub" data-canonical-src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_red_aa0000.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS should be

```
.ribbon{
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/piqinore/2/

Did you check the official github page to incorporate this ribbon , check it out at

> https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons

Comment: But here you are using an image instead of css. I wish to have a CSS solution.